# How do I modified my code such that different stock price is used with different random number

Tags: r

I have a code that looks that this, What I am trying to do is to simulate stock path, however, obviously I was using the same random number for the same row vector (a particular stock path) How do i modify this such that I could use a different random number for a stock price. Thanks for any comments.

```
options_monte_DO <- function(r, q, sigma, T, n, m, k, s_0, B) {
  x <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=m)
  y <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=m)
  dt <- T/m
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x[i, ] <- s_0*exp(cumsum((r - q - 0.5*sigma^2)*dt + 
                               sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(n, 0, 1)))
  }
  y <- x
  y[rowSums(x < B) > 0, ] <- NA
  option_payoff <- exp(-r*T)*pmax(k - y[, m], 0)
  z <- mean(option_payoff, na.rm=T)
  hist(option_payoff)
  return(z)
}
```

Comment: Please give a function call example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ?

Comment: in here I was only using n random variables but i have a n x m matrix, thus i am suppose to use n x m random number. But i am not sure how to account for that.

Comment: `options_monte_DO` is a function, how do you call it, with what values for its arguments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  But `rnorm(n,0,1))` does not seem to make sense because `n` in the pdf function is the number of realizations that are generated.  So 1, 2, 3...n.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: @SteveM Actually, I believe it should be an *m*: `rnorm(m,0,1)`. The loop seems to be filling matrix `x` by rows.

Comment: @Rui Barradas.  No With `rnom` the `n` or `m` are not matrix indexes, they are iteration counts.  E.g., r(n=1, 0, 1) is one realization of an N(0, 1) sampling.

Comment: @SteveM Yes, I know, but the loop is filling the matrix `x[i, ] <- vector_of_length_m` .